# Image for item menu action bar sherlock

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

I am adding two images in my menu action bar sherlock. The image2 is big than normal size. So image appear correctly in most device:

[image]

For recent device (like S4) i have a problem image appear so small. This doesn't look ok.
[image]

I am using action bar sherlock library

Comment: pls post the xml that displays that image.

Comment: haytham do not just put ur foto in xxhdpi . you have to put a bigger one there (I suppose 2.5 x that in mdpi)

Answer (score 1):

**IF** you have a large number of images to be displayed by your app, then creating different versions for mdpi, hdpi etc may take up too much space and create an unacceptable maintenance overhead for you.

In this case I suggest that you resize your images dynamically. I use the following code to resize 320 x 200 png and jpg images for tablets and they look fine ...

```
    // method to display image (tablets only) ...
    private void display_image(String imagename){

        if (isTablet(getActivity())){  // tablets only
           debugLog( "display tablet image="+imagename);
           int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename,"drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());                       // the corresponding resource id
           if (resID != 0) {
              Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);
              int width=480;
              int height=300;
              Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
              ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tablet_image);  // the imageview to change
              //imageView.setImageResource(resID);
              imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

S4 is XHDPI, so you need to have the XHDPI icon

Comment: S4 is xxhdpi, so you need xxhdpi icon